# "He mentioned that time and speeds are critical factors in successful deployment."

Tags: tense, backshifting

> He mentioned that time and speeds **are** critical factors in successful deployment.

Is the above sentence correct or wrong?

Comment: I don't understand how this phrase might be causing you confusion. It is correct.

Comment: The only problem I can see is that "speeds" is plural, so unless the context of this is referring to multiple objects with individual speeds (which it doesn't seem to be), that should be singular instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was a funny confusion! But great feeling for your kind efforts.